# Yii: Validate base64 image in model

Tags: php, yii, model, yii2

I have an input in a form like this:

```
  <?=  $form->field($model, 'imageFile', ['inputOptions' => ['id' => 'Imageupload']])->hiddenInput()->label(false) ?>
```

The fieldd cointains a picture as a base64 string like this:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...
```

My model validation rule contains this statement:

```
  public function rules() {
        return [
          [['imageFile'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg'],
        ];
    }
```

But it seems this does not work on a base64 string. 
Is there a way to validate it in the model, or do I have to generate a real image in the controller and THEN validate it with diverse php functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation rule doesn't work as expected because your field type is not a type `file` and also you are storing the image data manually as a `base64` encoded string. Now to solve your problem you could manually check the file type by making use of a PHP code as given below.

```
$model->imageFile = "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIA...";

$mimetype = getImageMimeType($model->imageFile);

echo $mimetype;

function getBytesFromHexString($hexdata) {
    for ($count = 0; $count < strlen($hexdata); $count += 2)
        $bytes[] = chr(hexdec(substr($hexdata, $count, 2)));

    return implode($bytes);
}

function getImageMimeType($imageString) {
    $imagedata = base64_decode($imageString);
    $imagemimetypes = array(
        "jpeg" => "FFD8",
        "png" => "89504E470D0A1A0A",
        "gif" => "474946",
        "bmp" => "424D",
        "tiff" => "4949",
        "tiff" => "4D4D"
    );

    foreach ($imagemimetypes as $mime => $hexbytes) {
        $bytes = getBytesFromHexString($hexbytes);
        if (substr($imagedata, 0, strlen($bytes)) == $bytes)
            return $mime;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```